# Undefined symbols for architecture i386: error in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am working on translation App for that i use marketplace azure and its client and so on ,in that app only i am using ocr tesseract for text scanning then apply translation as translate in required in language,
i am getting an bellow error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFHTTPRequestOperation", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FGTranslateRequest.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONResponseSerializer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FGTranslateRequest.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFXMLParserResponseSerializer", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FGTranslateRequest.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TMCache", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in FGTranslator.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

guide me ...

Comment: Are the classes AFHTTPRequestOperation, AFJSONResponseSerializer etc added to your project and included in the right target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type of errors normally occurs if your class' .m file is not listed under the "Compile Sources". Normally it's done by xcode but if there is any target related problem it fails to do it.

Steps:

> TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> Add Your .m Class ->Build and Run